# Is it possible to execute Teradata FastLoad or MultiLoad scripts through VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, odbc, teradata

I am able to run Normal DML scripts (INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE) scripts through VBA ODBC connection.

**But Is it possible to run FLOAD or MLOAD scripts through VBA ODBC ?**

I have large set of data and i want to write a VBA code for FLOAD / MLOAD to insert the data very quickly rather than normal DML scripts.

I heard that FLOAD / MLOAD can be executed from Unix or Mainframe systems. Is it possible to run from VBA ? If yes can you please help with some sample ?

Below is sample Teradata FLOAD script.

```
.LOGTABLE DB.Table_Log;
.LOGON oneview/uid,pwd;
.BEGIN IMPORT MLOAD TABLES DB.FRC_RPT_PERD SESSIONS 5;
.LAYOUT InputFile_layout;
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

From some brief research it appears MLOAD and FLOAD are command line utilities (.EXE)

If that is correct you would run it like this in VBA:

```
Shell(sCmdLine, vbHide)
```

Where `sCmdLine` is a string variable holding your command line

This site suggests your command line might be

```
mload < example.txt
```

http://datawarehouse.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/teradata-l/multiload-script-2193378

Anyway the first thing to do is work out your command line. Then you just run that from VBA. You will of course need all the Teradata client tools installed on the machine with VBA. Maybe that's your issue?